# How do I convert from LPCTSTR to std::string?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

I have an `LPCTSTR` and want to call a function that takes a `std::string` parameter.

What conversion do I need to do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Tip of the iceberg

`LPCTSTR` can be either a single-byte or a multibyte string (depends on the `UNICODE` constant being defined during compilation or not), while `std::string`'s users (including your function) normally use it to hold a single-byte string.

You 'd need two conversions: one for `LPCSTR` (non-`UNICODE` build) and one for `LPCWSTR` (`UNICODE` build). The first one is simple:

```
std::string convert(LPCSTR str) {
    return std::string(str);
}
```

The second one needs its input parameter to be converted to another encoding first with [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Do not be alarmed by the name, the result *can* be a single-byte char string; that depends on the `CodePage` parameter. You will have to use a codepage for a single-byte encoding, such as `CP_ACP`.

**Update: `WideCharToMultiByte` example**

**Be aware that accurately converting to a single-byte encoding is technically impossible if the input string contains characters not existing in the target encoding's code page.** Since you mention it's going to be for filesystem functions, if the file path contains such characters the conversion will not be 100% accurate and the subsequent function calls will fail.

```
std::string MBFromW(LPCWSTR pwsz, UINT cp) {
    int cch = WideCharToMultiByte(cp, 0, pwsz, -1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL);

    char* psz = new char[cch];

    WideCharToMultiByte(cp, 0, pwsz, -1, psz, cch, NULL, NULL);

    std::string st(psz);
    delete[] psz;

   return st;
}
```

**Caveat emptor:** The example above is from some code I had lying around and is not production-grade quality. The one immediately obvious flaw is that it is not exception-safe. It might also kill all the nice purple unicorns. Use it only as an *example*.

### The full encoding hell

The naked truth is that `std::string` can be used for multibyte encodings (such as UTF8) just fine -- you can even use it to hold wide-char strings, since it's just a binary-safe array of bytes at heart.

The problem is that *the STL functions that apply to `std::string` expect its contents to be in a single-byte encoding*, and they won't produce correct results if this is not true.

By extension, **we don't know what your function that takes an `std::string` parameter expects** -- it might expect a string encoded in UTF-8. But "by convention", I 'm assuming it also wants a single-byte-encoded string.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it is a UNICODE build (with `#define UNICODE` set). The function I am calling will take the `std::string` and use it as the filename when calling `std::fstream::open()` - so looks like WideCharToMultiByte is the way to go. That's a lot of parameters though - any chance of extending your answer to include an example of calling that function?

Comment: @GrahamS: Sure. I grepped and found some relevant old code of mine.

Comment: @GrahamS: Please be aware of all the pitfalls. The STL does not provide support for non-ANSI file paths AFAIK, so you may hit some hard obstacles here. It's even possible that you will be forced to abandon the STL.

Comment: @Jon: Actually, that's a Microsoft extension. And if you're already using `LPCTSTR`, you're not restricting yourself further by using `fstream::fstream(const wchar_t *filename)`. In fact, with that overload, it could be said that `fstream::fstream` already takes an `LPCTSTR`

Comment: @MSalters: I 've never seen `LPCTSTR` outside a Windows context, so I assumed `WideCharToMultiByte` is not a problem -- unless you are referring to something else as a MS extension? Also, the answer addresses the original question (no mention of `fstream`).

Comment: @Jon: `WideCharToMultiByte` will "work" on all current Windows versions, that's not the problem. But see the notes on `WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS` - you must specify how it deals with failure. And for `CP_ACP`, the vast majority of possible input is invalid.

Comment: @MSalters: These are issues with *any* MB to W conversion, aren't they?

Comment: @Jon: Not for UTF-8, that's still Unicode. And that's why you _can't_ use `WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS` with `CP_UTF8`. But you can't use `CP_UTF8` here; `std::fstream::fstream(char const*)` will use `CP_ACP` for the conversion back to `WCHAR`.

Comment: @MSalters: Ouch -- mistake in my last comment. I meant "W to MB", and specifically the case "W to SB". So you 're right of course about UTF but that's not the issue here.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks for your help. I lightly modified your example code by wrapping the conversion buffer in a `boost::scoped_array` to add some exception safety. That got it working for now, but based on @MSalters answer I'm going to press the library owner to modify his interface to accept an `LPCTSTR` or `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` and avoid this horrible conversion issue altogether :)

Comment: inline std::string convert(LPCSTR str) { return std::string(str); }  error C2664: 'convert' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'LPCTSTR' to 'LPCSTR'

Answer (score 16):

in one line:

```
std::string s = CT2A( lpctstr );
```

Answer (score 2):

Pragmatic approach:

```
     LPCTSTR input;

     std::string s;

#ifdef UNICODE
     std::wstring w;
     w = input;
     s = std::string(w.begin(), w.end()); // magic here
#else
     s = input;
#endif
```

See other answers for excellent backgrounders!

Comment: `error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::wstring' (or there is no acceptable conversion)` at the `s = w` line, do I need more magic?

Comment: This "works" in the US and Western Europe (ACP = latin-1). It breaks in interesting ways everywhere else.

Comment: Agreed. See heading "Pragmatic Approach" and disclaimer "See other answers for excellent backgrounders!" (note exclamation point). I voted your comment, so it will be extra visible

Answer (score 2):

From your comment: "The function I am calling will take the std::string and use it as the filename when calling std::fstream::open()"

Well, that's wrong. The function really should take a `tstring` (defined as `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring`). There are many Windows files whose name cannot be represented without Unicode. For instance, all files under `\User\<myusername\My Documents\` if `<myUserName>` contains a non-ANSI character (and you really don't want to tell your user that he has a bad name!)

But once you've changed to `tstring`, it just works. You still get the same `std::fstream` object.

Comment: +1 A fair point. Sadly I'm not responsible for the library that function is in so I can't change it, but I will raise that point with the author though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`LPCTSTR` is a Windows define that reads as something like 'long pointer to a const character-type string.' I'm not actually sure what the T stands for, but it has to do with the project's character set.

If your project is using the Unicode character set, this type is a `const wchar_t*`, which uses two bytes per character. If your project is using the multi-byte characters character set, this type is a `const char*`, which uses one byte per character.

Most likely your project's character set is Unicode, so `LPCTSTR` is a `const wchar_t*`. Since `std::string` uses one byte per character, it can't hold this two byte per character string. `std::wstring` can, however.

If you need to convert the `const wchar_t*` to a `const char*` to allow it to be assigned to a string, you can use functions like `wcstombs` to do this. If you're including ATL (specifically `atlconv.h`) in your project, it provides macros to do this more easily:

```
USES_CONVERSION;
const wchar_t* = L"Wide string";
std::string str = W2A(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet of code should do conversion from LPWSTR to char*/std::string

```
LPWSTR input = L"whatever";
int cSize = WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, 0, input, wcslen(input), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
std::string output(static_cast<size_t>(cSize), '\0');
WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, 0, input, wcslen(input),
                       reinterpret_cast<char*>(&output[0]), cSize, NULL, NULL);
```

and this snippet should do conversion from single-byte std::string to LPWSTR

```
std::string input = "whatever";
//computing wchar size:
int wSize = MultiByteToWideChar (CP_ACP, 0, (LPCSTR) input.c_str (), -1, 0, 0);

//allocating memory for wchar:
LPWSTR output = new WCHAR[wSize];

//conversion from string to LPWSTR:
MultiByteToWideChar (CP_ACP, MB_PRECOMPOSED , (LPCSTR) input.c_str (), -1, output, wSize);
```

Comment: I'm going the other way though: `LPCTSTR` to `std::string`

Comment: sorry I just realized that; i am looking the other way conversion snippet

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this [solution](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/531464-lpctstr-std-string) might help you.