# Getting an access violation while trying to store folderpath, possible error in LPSTR / String conversion

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to get the local Appdata folder, and store it in a string. I seem to be doing something wrong with my variables though, since I am getting an access violation when I try to store the folderpath into a string.

Code:

```
PSTR buffer;
HRESULT hRes = SHGetSpecialFolderPathA(NULL, buffer, CSIDL_APPDATA, FALSE);
std::string executingPathFolder = buffer;
```

Comment: `buffer` point to what ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/bb762204(v=vs.85).aspx)

> lpszPath [out]
>
> A pointer to a null-terminated string that receives the drive and path of the specified folder. This buffer must be at least MAX_PATH characters in size.

You must be careful with WinAPI - some methods returning buffers allocates them, some like write to allocated buffer. Please look here how to constructy std::string from LPSTR [How do I convert from LPCTSTR to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513718/how-do-i-convert-from-lpctstr-to-stdstring)

Comment: *A pointer to a null-terminated string ..* - this is wrong. `lpszPath` must point to buffer at least `MAX_PATH` characters in size. but initial context of the buffer does not matter.

Comment: I have tried to use those solutions, but they dont work, i am still getting an access violaten