# How to convert LPCTSTR to std::string in C++

Tags: c++, stdstring

I am having a function which takes arguments as LPCTSTR

I want to concatenate that argument in that function with a std::string

As per one of the suggestions I used following conversion:

```
std::string PlaybackStart(LPCTSTR i_bstrCameraName)
{
    wstring cid = (WCHAR*)i_bstrCameraName;
    string fcid;
    for (char x : cid)
        fcid += x;

   std::string myURL = "SOME IP";

   **//I want to concatenate myURL with i_bstrCameraName here**

   return myURL;
}
```

but this is leading to loss of data for example value passsed in arguments is "abcdefg" but my fcid gets a value as "aceg".

Comment: Why do you use an `LPCTSTR` when you continue with a std::string? What is your UNICODE setting and what is supposed to happen when you compile it the other way round?

Comment: This already has an answer in Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513718/how-do-i-convert-from-lpctstr-to-stdstring

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert from LPCTSTR to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513718/how-do-i-convert-from-lpctstr-to-stdstring)

Comment: if your source string is `'ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'g'` you're probably doing it wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LPCTSTR` is an alias for `const TCHAR*`, where `TCHAR` is either `char` or `wchar_t`, depending on project configuration.

The cast of `i_bstrCameraName` to `WCHAR*` is wrong if your project is configured to map `TCHAR` to `char`. Just use the `char` data as-is instead.

And the conversion of `wchar_t` characters to `char` in the `for` loop is wrong if `TCHAR` is configured to map to `wchar_t` instead. That will lose data for non-ASCII characters. You would need to use `WideCharToMultiByte()` or equivalent to *convert* the `wchar_t` data to `char` properly.

You really should not be using `TCHAR`-based functionality in modern code at all. That has not been needed since the days when Microsoft was migrating users from ANSI-based Win9x/ME to Unicode-based WinNT+.

But, if you must, your code should look more like this instead:

```cpp
std::string PlaybackStart(LPCTSTR i_bstrCameraName)
{
    string fcid;

    #ifdef UNICODE
    int wlen = lstrlenW(i_bstrCameraName);
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, i_bstrCameraName, wlen, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    fcid.resize(len);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, i_bstrCameraName, wlen, &fcid[0], len, NULL, NULL);
    #else
    fcid = i_bstrCameraName;
    #endif

    std::string myURL = "SOME IP";

    myURL += fcid;

    return myURL;
}
```

That being said, the parameter name `i_bstrCameraName` suggests that the parameter should actually be declared as a `BSTR`, not an `LPCTSTR`. `BSTR` is an alias for `OLECHAR*` aka `wchar_t*`, eg:

```cpp
std::string PlaybackStart(BSTR i_bstrCameraName)
{
    string fcid;

    int wlen = SysStringLen(i_bstrCameraName);
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, i_bstrCameraName, wlen, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    fcid.resize(len);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, i_bstrCameraName, wlen, &fcid[0], len, NULL, NULL);

    std::string myURL = "SOME IP";

    myURL += fcid;

    return myURL;
}
```